# Storybook won't start: TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation

Tags: angular, webpack, yarnpkg, storybook, nrwl-nx

Trying to start Storybook in a NX monorepo, but getting this error when trying these commands:

`nx run projectName:storybook` `nx storybook projectName` :

```
9% setup compilation SourceMapDevToolPlugin
C:\Users\userName\Documents\Git\bft3\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptModulesPlugin.js:143
                        throw new TypeError(
                              ^

TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
    at Function.getCompilationHooks (C:\Users\userName\Documents\Git\bft3\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptModulesPlugin.js:143:10)
    at SourceMapDevToolModuleOptionsPlugin.apply (C:\Users\userName\Documents\Git\bft3\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolModuleOptionsPlugin.js:50:27)
    at C:\Users\userName\Documents\Git\bft3\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:163:53
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\Users\userName\Documents\Git\bft3\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:374:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (C:\Users\userName\Documents\Git\bft3\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (C:\Users\userName\Documents\Git\bft3\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1122:26)
    at C:\Users\userName\Documents\Git\bft3\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1166:29
    at _next0 (eval at create (C:\Users\userName\Documents\Git\bft3\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:41:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\userName\Documents\Git\bft3\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:55:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

By reading other, similar posts i think it could be because of multiple versions of webpack.

Here are the related packages/deps:
`yarn list --pattern "webpack"`

```
├─ @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.2.9
│  └─ webpack@5.74.0
├─ @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1402.9
├─ @cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.15.5
├─ @ngtools/webpack@14.2.9
├─ @nrwl/angular@15.0.13
│  └─ webpack-merge@5.7.3
├─ @nrwl/cypress@15.0.13
│  └─ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@7.2.13
├─ @nrwl/webpack@15.0.13
│  ├─ copy-webpack-plugin@10.2.4
│  ├─ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@7.2.13
│  └─ webpack-dev-server@4.11.1
├─ @storybook/builder-webpack4@6.5.13
│  ├─ terser-webpack-plugin@4.2.3
│  ├─ webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3
│  ├─ webpack-sources@1.4.3
│  ├─ webpack-virtual-modules@0.2.2
│  └─ webpack@4.46.0
│     └─ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
├─ @storybook/builder-webpack5@6.5.13
│  ├─ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2
│  ├─ html-webpack-plugin@5.5.0
│  └─ webpack-dev-middleware@4.3.0
├─ @storybook/core-common@6.5.13
│  ├─ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2
│  ├─ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
│  ├─ webpack-sources@1.4.3
│  └─ webpack@4.46.0
├─ @storybook/core-server@6.5.13
│  ├─ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
│  ├─ webpack-sources@1.4.3
│  └─ webpack@4.46.0
├─ @storybook/manager-webpack4@6.5.13
│  ├─ terser-webpack-plugin@4.2.3
│  ├─ webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3
│  ├─ webpack-sources@1.4.3
│  ├─ webpack-virtual-modules@0.2.2
│  └─ webpack@4.46.0
│     └─ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
├─ @storybook/manager-webpack5@6.5.13
│  ├─ html-webpack-plugin@5.5.0
│  └─ webpack-dev-middleware@4.3.0
├─ @types/webpack-env@1.18.0
├─ @types/webpack-sources@3.2.0
├─ @types/webpack@4.41.33
├─ case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin@2.4.0
├─ copy-webpack-plugin@11.0.0
├─ css-minimizer-webpack-plugin@3.4.1
├─ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@4.1.6
├─ html-webpack-plugin@4.5.2
├─ license-webpack-plugin@4.0.2
├─ pnp-webpack-plugin@1.6.4
├─ terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.6
├─ tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin@3.5.2
├─ webpack-bundle-analyzer@4.7.0
├─ webpack-dev-middleware@5.3.3
├─ webpack-dev-server@4.11.0
├─ webpack-filter-warnings-plugin@1.2.1
├─ webpack-hot-middleware@2.25.3
├─ webpack-log@2.0.0
├─ webpack-merge@5.8.0
├─ webpack-node-externals@3.0.0
├─ webpack-sources@3.2.3
├─ webpack-subresource-integrity@5.1.0
├─ webpack-virtual-modules@0.4.6
└─ webpack@5.75.0
```

I'm not quite experienced enough to debug this completely, so do you see an issue here with webpack or have any other idea what might be causing this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using webpack version 5.64 fixed this issue for me!

Answer (score 2):

Try to fix the `webpack` version to `v5.74.0` in `package.json` file. It worked for me!

```json
...
"webpack": "5.74.0"
```

Then run `yarn` to force install the selected version.

Comment: Thanks for your input, that version had the same error though

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the webpack conflict with overrides in package.json.

I verify the webpack version:

```
npm ls webpack
```

Then add the override version:

```
 "overrides": {
     "webpack": "5.80.0"
 }
```

Also with resolutions:

```
 "resolutions": {
        "webpack": "5.80.0"
  },
```